# Can I update two arrays in the same item with one query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have groups in my app. Users can join and invite other users. In the db I store it like this:

```
Group = {
   users: [UserId: ObjectId],
   invitations: [email: string]
}
```

When a user accepts the invitation I want to put them from invitations to users:

```
join: (req, res, next) => {
    Group.findOneAndUpdate(
        {invitations: {$elemMatch: {email: req.user.email}}},
        {$pullAll: {invitations: req.user.email}, $addToSet: {users: req.user._id}})
        .then(succ => {
            console.log(succ);
            next()
        })
        .catch(err => {
            error(res, err)
        });
},
```

Unfortunately this is not working for me. Is it possible somehow to make the two changes with one query? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can update two array in a single Query, you are doing it almost right, just a simple mistake. you need to pull just one element from the array, so i think you should use `$pull` instead of `$pullAll` , this will work better in your case. `$pull` takes an element, while `$pullAll` takes an array, so you are better with `$pull`.

just replace `$pullAll` with `$pull`, and it will work.

Try this:

```
Group.findOneAndUpdate(
    {invitations: {$elemMatch: {email: req.user.email}}},
    {$pull: {invitations: req.user.email}, $addToSet: {users: req.user._id}})
    .then(succ => {
        console.log(succ);
        next()
    })
    .catch(err => {
        error(res, err)
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

[`$pullAll`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) requires an array in argument like `$pullAll: { "invitations": [ "1", "2" ] }`. And you need to specify the nested document `{ "email": req.user.email }`, the same apply for `$addToSet` : `{ "UserId": req.user._id }`.

The query would be :

```
Group.findOneAndUpdate({
        "invitations": {
            $elemMatch: {
                "email": req.user.email
            }
        }
    }, {
        $pullAll: {
            "invitations": [{ "email": req.user.email }]
        },
        $addToSet: {
            "users": { "UserId": req.user._id }
        }
    })
    .then(succ => {
        console.log(succ);
        next()
    })
    .catch(err => {
        error(res, err)
    });
```